# isInfoEnabled () for Commons Logging

Tags: java, logging, log4j, apache-commons-logging

I am using `logger.info("statement" + string)` in lot of places in my applications including **for loops** and **if** statements.

I checked and found out that the string message get created first even when "`INFO`" level is not enabled.

How to check if `INFO` is enabled before the string gets created without adding the `isInfoEnabled()` at each place where I implemented it.

Also, what's the best way to reduce overheads while using logger.

Instead of  `+` how would it be better if we use a utility method like returning a concatenated string using a `Stringbuilder`.

I am using `log4j.xml` for configuring the logger lever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper solution is to use slf4j/logback, which support passing in raw data without up-front string generation. With Commons Logging this can't be done and performance won't improve if you replace `+` with `StringBuilder` since string concatenation expressions are already compiled into code that involves a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to create Utility call for that, your own architecture over Logger

something like this (pseudocode, I don't know about Logger implementation)

```
class OwnLogger extends Logger {

    public static function info(Object o){
        if(isInfoEnabled()){
            super.info(o);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I am using commons logging and not log4j. Can this work on commons logging ?

Comment: @DebajyotiDas this is abstract for any logging utility, allows you to put the `isInfoEnabled` only in one place.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more on how to create a utility method?